# Major and minor grid lines and ticks using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have two big intergers

```
min=round(raw_min,-5) # a negative number
max=round(raw_max,-5)
```

from which I get a range of interesting ticks:

```
xticks=np.arange(min,max,500000)
```

On the x-axis, I want to have minor ticks (including labels) for the `xticks` range. Furthermore, I want to have a major tick and grid line at the value `0`. I tried to add:

```
minorLocator = FixedLocator(xticks)
majorLocator = FixedLocator([0])

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(majorLocator)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%d'))
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(minorLocator)
plt.tick_params(which='both', width=1)
plt.tick_params(which='major', length=7, color='b')
plt.tick_params(which='minor', length=4, color='r')
ax.yaxis.grid(True)
ax.xaxis.grid(b=True,which='major', color='b', linestyle='-')
```

but it doesn't work...

[image]

No ticks for the minors and no grid line for the major.

Any ideas?

Comment: "Doesn't work" means no graph at all? No ticks? Ticks in the wrong place? No grid lines?

Answer (score 2):

Seems like I was missing the following line:

```
plt.grid(b=True,which='both')
```